# How to treat request from HTTP and HTTPS inseparately Spring Boot 2 to run Tomcat on two separate ports?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, security, controller

I am adding the secure port with the non-secure port already opened. I wants to separate the traffic between two and forward to different Spring boot 2 Controllers. Wonder how I can achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

In most solutions I have seen so far, https / SSL is terminated infront of Tomcat or Spring Boot application, so that Tomcat / Spring Controller receives only http requests on port 8080 (for example).

Termination of SSL in front of Tomcat / Spring Boot could be done with a Reverse Proxy or Web Server, like Apache2 or nginx.

Then the communication flow looks like this:

- User ==HTTP-80==> Apache2 ==HTTP-8080==> Tomcat/Spring Boot
- User ==HTTPS-443==> Apache2 ==HTTP-8080==> Tomcat/Spring Boot

("HTTP-80" means HTTP protocol on port 80. "== ==>" is arrow showing communication flow.)